# Trying to write array to range of cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, ribbon

Here's the gist what I'm doing. I have a ribbon button which needs to read a simple 2 column CSV file into a 1-dimensional array row-by-row, and then I need to write the array into the first two columns in excel.

I have it successfully reading into the array (the msgbox line below confirms), but I can't for the life of me get anything to be written into the sheet.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Public Class MyRibbon

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim filename As String = "C:\DATA_csvtest.TXT"
        Dim fields As String()
        Dim delimiter As String = ","
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filename)
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                ' Read in the fields for the current line
                fields = parser.ReadFields()
                ' Add code here to use data in fields variable.

                MsgBox(fields(0) + " " + fields(1)) 'verifies above code is working

                Range("A1:B1").Value2 = fields

            End While
        End Using

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159

    End Sub



    Private Sub MyRibbon_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

In the `Button1_Click` sub, I'm getting the error "Range is a type and cannot be used as an expression" on `Range("A1:B1").Value2 = fields`.

In the `Button2_Click` sub, I just wanted to see if I could write a static value to a single cell. I found that exact line of code on a different SO or maybe MSDN post... I can't recall now. Either way, I'm getting "'Worksheet' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types '`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`'."

I'm relatively new to this, but I've tried literally HUNDREDS of sources/methods for importing delimited data into excel, more-so specifically writing data to a cell/range.

Does anyone see what I'm missing/doing wrong here? Or maybe have another thing I can try for writing data to a cell/range?

Comment: So you are on VB.NET and you want to create a new Excel Workbook and add the value of the CSV file, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value=3.14159`

Comment: I tried that, getting this error:

'ActiveWorkbook' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 0):

Did your code in Button_2 work? I think you might need to use something like the following.

`Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2 = 3.14159`

And with your first bit of code, does your data file have one row and two columns? because if there are multiple rows it looks like you'll just overwrite the first cells after each iteration.

You could increment the row number each iteration (simplest) or you could *insert* and *move down* over the first cells to make it push the previous iterations down. You could also create a larger array containing all the data and just set all rows at once.